# Xamarin Media Plugin Crashes on Recording Video Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm currently using Xamarin.Forms and its [Media Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) to record a video for my app. I have followed the instructions on the plugins' readme but it still gives me this error when I try to record a video.

```
Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
06-22 16:21:24.741 I/mono-stdout( 3232): Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
06-22 16:21:24.741 I/mono-stdout( 3232):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+StaticMethods.CallStaticObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in <bd30a18775d94dc8b6263aecd1ca9077>:0 
at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod (System.IntPtr jclass, System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x0000e] in <d855bac285f44dda8a0d8510b679b1e2>:0 
at Android.Support.V4.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile (Android.Content.Context context, System.String authority, Java.IO.File file) [0x00078] in <3e239b9681084d42bb949c1e01ef500e>:0 
06-22 16:21:24.743 I/mono-stdout( 3232):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+StaticMethods.CallStaticObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in <bd30a18775d94dc8b6263aecd1ca9077>:0 
06-22 16:21:24.743 I/mono-stdout( 3232):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod (System.IntPtr jclass, System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x0000e] in <d855bac285f44dda8a0d8510b679b1e2>:0 
06-22 16:21:24.743 I/mono-stdout( 3232):   at 
Android.Support.V4.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile (Android.Content.Context context, System.String authority, Java.IO.File file) [0x00078] in <3e239b9681084d42bb949c1e01ef500e>:0 
at Plugin.Media.MediaPickerActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x00212] in C:\projects\mediaplugin\src\Media.Plugin.Android\MediaPickerActivity.cs:172 
06-22 16:21:24.745 I/mono-stdout( 3232):   at Plugin.Media.MediaPickerActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x00212] in C:\projects\mediaplugin\src\Media.Plugin.Android\MediaPickerActivity.cs:172
```

This is my code

```
await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsTakeVideoSupported || !CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable)
{
    await DisplayAlert("Error", "Taking video is not supported on your device", "Ok");
    return;
}

MediaFile file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakeVideoAsync(new StoreVideoOptions() // Exception thrown here
{
    Name = "video.mp4",
    Directory = "DefaultVideos"
});
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" package="com/myapp">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
              android:required="true" />

    <application android:label="MyApp" android:icon="@drawable/Icon">
    <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.myapp.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is my AssemblyInfo.cs

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Android.App;

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("MyApp")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("MyApp")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2014")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]

// Add some common permissions, these can be removed if not needed
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.Internet)]
```

and my file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
  <external-path name="my_movies" path="Videos" />
</paths>
```

Edit: After changing

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" package="com/myapp">
```

to

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" package="com.myapp">
```

I now get a new error:

```
06-23 14:55:25.305 I/mono-stdout( 3010): Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp/files/Movies/DefaultVideos/video.mp4
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+StaticMethods.CallStaticObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in <bd30a18775d94dc8b6263aecd1ca9077>:0 
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod (System.IntPtr jclass, System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x0000e] in <d855bac285f44dda8a0d8510b679b1e2>:0 
  at Android.Support.V4.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile (Android.Content.Context context, System.String authority, Java.IO.File file) [0x00078] in <3e239b9681084d42bb949c1e01ef500e>:0 
 06-23 14:55:25.305 I/mono-stdout( 3010):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at Plugin.Media.MediaPickerActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x00212] in C:\projects\mediaplugin\src\Media.Plugin.Android\MediaPickerActivity.cs:172
```

Two things about that error seem strange. The first is that path at the top of the error has `com.myapp` instead of `com/myapp`. The second is that at the bottom of the error it is referencing a path that doesn't exist and I don't know how to change.

Comment: Can you please post your code for recording video here?

Comment: Done @GraceFeng-MSFT